# python3 kivy BoxLayout over another

Tags: python, kivy, boxlayout

I looked at the documentation to know how to place my Box Layout in my kivy window

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html

but i want to place my BoxLayout over another (with transparent background) like this :

[image]

my code (without my five transparent red box)

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.button import Button



# Boxlayout is the App class

class BoxLayoutDemo(App):

    def build(self):

        superBox        = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')



        horizontalBox   = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')

        button1         = Button(text="One")

        button2         = Button(text="Two")



        horizontalBox.add_widget(button1)

        horizontalBox.add_widget(button2)



        verticalBox     = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        button3         = Button(text="Three")

        button4         = Button(text="Four")



        verticalBox.add_widget(button3)

        verticalBox.add_widget(button4)



        superBox.add_widget(horizontalBox)

        superBox.add_widget(verticalBox)



        return superBox





# Instantiate and run the kivy app

if __name__ == '__main__':

    BoxLayoutDemo().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [FloatLayout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html#kivy.uix.floatlayout.FloatLayout) as your root widget, and [pos_hint: {'top': 1}](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint) so that you can place the transparent BoxLayout at the top. As for transparency, use Button's [background_normal and background_color](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html).

## Snippets

```
FloatLayout:
...
    # topBox
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Five (with transparent red background)'
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 0.8, 0, 0, 0.5  # 5% red
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.1)
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:
    size: (300, 300)

    # superBox
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        # horizontalBox
        BoxLayout:
            # orientation: 'horizontal' - default orientation is horizontal
            Button:
                text: 'One'
            Button:
                text: 'Two'

        # verticalBox
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                text: 'Three'
            Button:
                text: 'Four'

    # topBox
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Five (with transparent red background)'
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 0.8, 0, 0, 0.5  # 5% red
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.1)
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}

'''))
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Answer (score 1):

Try put the boxlayouts in a floatlayout, like so:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


KV = """

<MyButton@Button>:
    background_color: (1,0,0,.5)

FloatLayout:

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "test"
        Button:
            text: "test"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MyButton:
            text: "test"
        MyButton:
            text: "test"

"""


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

MyApp().run()
```

output:

[image]